# Spring web service using JiBX

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jibx

I want to create Spring web services using JiBX. I already have my Java classes. How do I proceed? Can someone give me link to a  good tutorial
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoshang,
I don't have an example of exactly what you want, but this may help:

- The JiBX documentation has instructions on how you can bind your java
  classes to an xml schema. You can find the documentation [here](http://www.jibx.org).
- [Here](https://github.com/jibx/maven-plugin/tree/master/test-suite/org.jibx.test.bind) is an actual example from our source repo.
- Spring has and OXM mapper for JiBX [Here (see section 8.8)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html), but you will probably not use this.
- This [blog](http://blog.tourgeek.com/2012/04/creating-soap-and-rest-services-for.html) entry shows step-by-step how to create a xml web-service using blueprint, which is almost exactly the same as spring. (blueprint is the vendor-neutral spec authored by spring).
- You can find a very simple web-services example [here](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/schema-library/webservices.html). The source code for this example is [here](https://github.com/jibx/schema-library/tree/master/org.opentravel/_2011B/opentravel-ws).

I hope this helps!
Don